# What's the proper way of obtaining an account on CPAN?

Tags: perl, cpan

Can you please tell me the steps I need to follow in order to obtain an account on CPAN? I'd like to contribute some modules.
A while back, I tried to create an account, and I remember I got back a mail containing some of this text:

`The following links are only valid for PAUSE maintainers:` and there were 2 links :

- `Registration form with editing capabilities:`

and

- `Immediate (one click) registration:`

I remember I clicked on the `Immediate registration` but it asked me for a username & password.I did not knew how to go on from there. Was I going in the wrong direction? Does anyone have a step by step account registration tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the steps from the CPAN FAQ [PAUSE FAQ](http://www.cpan.org/modules/04pause.html).  You need to supply a user name and a password to create an account.

When I registered a couple years ago, the first email I got was a simple acknowledgement that I requested an account.  The second email was to welcome me as a new user; it notified me of an auto-generated password, and requested me to change my password.

It looks like you might be able to track your progress from this website: [PAUSE](http://www.xray.mpe.mpg.de/mailing-lists/modules/). 
Search for your user name.

I also ran a SuperSearch on PerlMonks to see if others have had problems with PAUSE.  This is what turned up:

[PAUSE ID](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=779191)

[Is PAUSE working?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=540136)

Answer (score 6):

It's been so long since I created my CPAN account that I almost forgot. But you need to go to http://pause.perl.org/ and click "Request a PAUSE Account". PAUSE is the upload backend for CPAN, and from there you can register your account, create a new module, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The perldoc for [perlnewmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnewmod.html) is a good starting point, and includes all the instructions you will need to setup your module properly for CPAN.

Answer (score 2):

Send email to [modules@perl.org](http://lists.perl.org/list/modules.html) for assistance. Browse the archives for your PAUSE id application.